# How to find places near your location with Yelp API v2

Tags: javascript, html, api, yelp

I know how to use most utilities on Yelp API v2, but I can't seem to figure out how to find stores near me. There is a section of the code that shows:

var terms = 'supermarkets';
var near = 'santa+clara';

This helps me find supermarkets near cupertino. But what do I put in "near" to find supermarkets near me (whereever I am)? I tried "current+location", but that doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to write a script (or find one) that would determinate your (or the user's) location first and than you'd use that to feed the "near" call.
By the way I don't think there is a "near" call. I think the call is "location"